# Numpy matrix minus a vector with repeated row/column indices

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
     [3, 4],
     [5, 6]])
>>>b
array([[1, 2],
     [4, 3]])
```

What I want is doing

```
b[0,:]-=a[0,:], b[1,:]-=a[1,:], b[0,:]-=a[2,:]
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
>>> b[[0,1,0],:]-=a
>>> b
array([[-4, -4], # want [-5, -6]
     [ 1, -1]])
```

How can this be achieved without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.subtract.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) -

```
np.subtract.at(b,[0,1,0],a)
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [16]: b
Out[16]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 3]])

In [17]: np.subtract.at(b,[0,1,0],a)

In [18]: b
Out[18]: 
array([[-5, -6],
       [ 1, -1]])
```

Comment: I didn't know about `.at` - thank you! Is it possible to do the same returning the result instead of changing data in-place?

Comment: @MaxU I am afraid that won't be any straight-forward if it all possible :)

Comment: This works, but seems inefficient. I doubt the implementation is not paralleled.

Comment: @YuanChen Inefficient compare to what? A for-loop? If its slower than a loopy version, how slow is it?

Comment: @Divakar Slow compared to other numpy functions. The speed is roughly the same as a for loop.